# How to pass values of nested Array to another Component - ReactJS/LaravelAPI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have an api that fetches the details of a single farm with its fruits and I want to show the details of the farm in one components and the fruit list in another component.

I have a button that when clicked, should open the component with the fruits.

The farm details is also fetched using `useParams` like this:

The Route

```
<Route path="farm-details/:username/:farmId" element={<FarmDetails />} />
```

The details

```
function FarmDetails() {
let navigate = useNavigate();
const [farm, setFarm] = useState('');
const { username } = useParams();
const { farmId } = useParams();
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
const user = React.useContext(UserContext);

useEffect(() => {

    let isMounted = true;

    axios.get(`/api/farm/${username}/${farmId}`).then(res => {
        if (isMounted) {
            if (res.data.status === 200) {
                setFarm(res.data.farm);
                setIsLoading(false);
                console.warn(res.data.farm)
            }
            else if (res.data.status === 404) {
                navigate('/');
                toast.error(res.data.message, "error");
            }
        }

    });

    return () => {
        isMounted = false
    };
}, []);
```

Now, the farm api has a nested array with a list of fruits, and I want to display the fruit list in another component with `farm.fruits && farm.fruits`

Somebody please help. Thank you

Comment: What are you wanting to pass and where are you wanting to pass it?

Comment: I want to pass the fruits details and I want to pass it to `farm-details/:username/:farmId/fruits`

Comment: Do you have a route for that path? Is there a link or a button a user clicks that navigates there and you want to pass the data? Can you provide a more complete [mcve] for what you are trying to do?